# backbone model get throws undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
app.Model.Brand = Backbone.Model.extend({});
app.Collection.BrandCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Model.Brand,
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.brandDTOList;
    }
});
var brandcollection = new app.Collection.BrandCollection();
brandcollection.url = '/brands';
brandcollection.fetch({
    success: function (collection, response, options) {
        app.views.brandline = new app.View.BrandPanelView({
            model: brandcollection
        });
        $('#tab-content').empty();
        $('#tab-content').append(app.views.brandline.render());
    }
});
```

In this view a single model is passed.

```
app.View.BrandItemPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.views = {};
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },
    events: {
        'click .bra-edt': 'brandEditAction',
    },
    brandEditAction: function () {
        this.model.get('image');
    }
});
```

When i do `this.model.get('image');` i get `get` is not a function.
I am not sure why i am getting such a error.

I tried to deep clone it but still no success. The values are there.

```
var newModel = new app.Model.Brand();
newModel = $.extend(true, {}, self.model);
newModel.get('image')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably not related but why do you have an `options` parameter on your `initialize` function?

Comment: Nice point...Looks like just copy paste effect. Removed it :)

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in `brandEditAction` do you still see your model in the debugger in `this.model` ? Do you see the values, the prototype methods?

Comment: where should this image attribute come from? "/brands" url?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you are passing in your *brandCollection* as a `model` instead of a `collection`. Most likely what you meant was `collection: brandcollection`.

Comment: Yeah but can that be a problem because i have a iterator and everything is workign fine..

Comment: Try moving your `model: app.Model.Brand` assignment to the initialize function of the collection, it's possible that it is `undefined` at that point. For example `initialize: function () { this.model = app.Model.Brand;}`.

Comment: Thanks jack. Because of passing collection into model , although the view was working okay but backbone model properties were getting lost.Now everything working fine

Comment: Glad to help, I'll put it into an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is where you are passing in your *BrandCollection*, instead of passing it in as a `collection` you are passing it in as a `model`.

So instead of

```
app.views.brandline = new app.View.BrandPanelView({
            model: brandcollection
});
```

You probably want to do

```
app.views.brandline = new app.View.BrandPanelView({
    collection: brandcollection
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you instantiating the BrandItemPanelView?

You will have to pass in the model explicitly:

```
var view = new app.View.BrandItemPanelView({ model: myModel });
```

If myModel is in fact a Backbone model, it ought to have the get function...

```
 view.model // should return your model
 view.brandEditAction() // should run the function and get the 'image' attribute from your model
```

Comment: His instantiating code is included in the first fragment